# Streaming Of ZeroMQ Events Back To Client

Tags: sockets, zeromq

I have a use case where by i wish to have a ZeroMQ Request / Reply socket 'stream' back results, is this possible with MultiPart messages (i.e. The Reply sockets streams the frames back before HasMore = false?) or am i approaching this incorrectly?

The situation:

1) Client makes a query (Request) for some records

2) Server looks up Database for results and responds with the current large amount records (Reply) split into frames

3) Server must wait until a Server Side event is generated before the final Frame is sent (HasMore = false)

4) Client wont get the previous Frames until the Final Event has been generated and HasMore = false

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand what you're aiming for, it sounds like what you have will work the way you expect. [See here for more discussion on message frames](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Working-with-Messages).  The salient points:

- As you say, all of the frames will be sent to the client at one time, they will be stored on the server until `HasMore` is set to `false`.
- One important thing to remember here, if it's a truly large amount of data, you must be able to fit the entire data set into memory, because it'll be stored in your server memory until the entire message with all frames is complete, and then it'll be received into memory before it's processed on the client side.

I assume primarily what you're looking for is a way to iteratively build up a message before you send it?  And perhaps to be able to deal with the data on the client iteratively as well?  Also you get a guarantee that you won't lose part of the data in the middle, you either get the whole message or lose the whole message (as opposed to instead sending each frame as a separate message).  This is one of the primary use cases for frames, so you've done well.

The only thing I object to is using the word "stream", as that implies that the data is being sent to the client continuously as it's being processed on the server, and that's explicitly not what you're trying to do (nor is it possible with ZMQ message frames).